# Extracting timestamps difference by day, minute and second in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp

I would like to get the difference between 2 timestamps both have the day and month but I would like to see the output as the largest value. Currently my output is showing the difference in years as well as months and days etc, but I only need to see the days and hours. Is there a way to do this?

This is the data using this code:

```
select  
id,
ts1 ,
ts2 ,
(ts2 - ts1) as output
from table_a
```

an example row (out of multiple):

```
 id |ts1                    | ts2                   | output                
 ---|-----------------------|-----------------------| -------------------- 
  3 |2020-04-27 11:00:46.00 |2020-04-27 12:52:04.00 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 1 hours 51 mins 18.00 secs
```

But I would like to show the shortest answer possible (so just days when necessary, hours, minutes and excluding seconds) so in this case just 1 hours 51 minutes etc

Desired result:

```
 id |ts1                    | ts2                   | output                
----|-----------------------|-----------------------| --------------------
  3 |2020-04-27 11:00:46.00 |2020-04-27 12:52:04.00 | 1 hours 51 mins
```

How do I do this (using postgresql) ?

Comment: `with t(ts1,ts2) as (values('2020-04-26 11:00:46.00'::timestamp, '2020-04-27 12:52:04.00'::timestamp)) select ts2-ts1 from t;` And result is `1 day 01:51:18` both in `psql` and in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6dcfbb4aa4939ae3708b31e9d2c9f858 What I doing wrong?

Comment: Please answer question already asked previously: running `with t(ts1,ts2) as (values('2020-04-27 11:00:46.00'::timestamp, '2020-04-27 12:52:04.00'::timestamp)) select ts2-ts1 from t;` returns `01:51:18`: this is what you need. Please give the right query you are using and the right data types.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, it is working now! thanks